Taking the functional derivative in Faddeev-Popov method
I am trying to obtain the ghost term in chapter 16.6 of Peskin (page 534) where he uses the background field method in order to compute the effective action for Yang-Mills theory.
In particular, suppose I perturb my gauge field around a background like so
$$ A_{\mu}^a = \overline{A}_{\mu}^a + a_{\mu}^a $$
where $\overline{A}_{\mu}$ is my classical background field and $a_{\mu}^a$ are the high-energy fluctuations. Denoting the covariant derivative with respect to the background field as $\overline{D}_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} - i \overline{A}_{\mu}^a t^a,$ we can denote the gauge transformation of the fluctuating field as
$$ a_{\mu}^a \rightarrow a_{\mu}^a + \overline{D}_{\mu} \alpha^a + f^{abc} a_{\mu}^b \alpha^c $$
where $\alpha$ is the gauge parameter and $f^{abc}$ denote the structure constants of the corresponding Lie algebra. Now, the gauge-fixing condition that Peskin writes down is the covariant one (eq. 16.97)
$$\overline{D}^{\mu} a_{\mu}^a = \omega^a $$
for some function $\omega^a(x)$. The Faddeev-Popov determinant is given by the determinant of the following
$$\frac{\delta (\overline{D}^{\mu} a_{\mu}^a(x) )}{\delta \alpha^c(y)} $$
where the $a^a_{\mu}$ in the numerator is the gauge-transformed one. When I try to compute this, I get
$$ \frac{\delta(\overline{D}^{\mu} a_{\mu}^a(x) +  \overline{D}^{\mu} \overline{D}_{\mu} \alpha^a(x) + f^{abc} \overline{D}^{\mu} (a_{\mu}^b(x) \alpha^c(x)) )}{\delta \alpha^c(y)} = -\overline{D}^2 \delta^{ac} \delta(x-y) - f^{abc} a^{b}_{\mu}(x) \overline{D}^{\mu} \delta(x-y)$$
where I just integrated by parts by assuming the expression is integrated. This would correspond to adding a ghost term of the form
$$ \overline{c}^a(-\overline{D}^2 - f^{abc}a^b_{\mu}\overline{D}^{\mu})c^c$$
however, Peskin gets the following (eq. 16.98)
$$ -\overline{c}^a\overline{D}^2 c^c - f^{abc}\overline{c}^a\overline{D}^{\mu}(a^b_{\mu}c^c)$$
where the $a_{\mu}$ sits inside the covariant derivative. I'm not sure where I went wrong in taking the functional derivative?
